# PropertyChanged is always null in ViewModelBase

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I made a simple example to better understan the MVVM pattern.
Here is a link to the sample solution, because its difficult to explain the whole problem:
http://www.2shared.com/file/jOOAnacd/MVVMTestMyCopy.html

There is `Employee` model (with `Age` property) and `EmployeeViewModel`, which contains `Employee` object and changes its `Age` property in the following code:

```
public int Age
{
    get { return _employee.Age; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _employee.Age)
            return;
        _employee.Age = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
    }
}
```

`EmployeeViewModel` is inherited from `ViewModelBase` class with standard INotifyPropertyCHanged code:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
}
```

I'm trying to change employee's age using ICommand:

```
public void Increase()
{
    this.SelectedEmployee.Age++;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
}
```

The property is changed, but the binded TextBLock does not change its value.
I checked and saw that `NotifyPropertyChanged` is called, but `PropertyChanged` is `null`.
I also ensured that I have only one `PeopleViewModel` in my app.
So, why is the `PropertyChanged` is `null`?

EDIT:
Here is full code for `ViewModelBase`:

```
public class ViewModelBase
{

    public String DisplayName { get; set; }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }


    #endregion

}
```

There is `PeopleViewModel` which contains `ObservalbleCollectio`n with `EmployeeViewModels` and set as `DataContext`.
The values of properties are changed, but the changes are not shown without reloading objects.

Here is the PeopleViewer.xaml that shows the binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMTestMyCopy.View.PeopleViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MVVMTestMyCopy.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="316" d:DesignWidth="410">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:PeopleViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Margin="5,5,4,5"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="2"
                                   Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2"
                                   Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0 2"
                                   Text="[" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2"
                                   Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0 2"
                                   Text="]" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.75*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.25*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="EmployeeDetails"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  DataContext="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
                  Margin="5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Grid.Row="2" />

            </Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                <Button x:Name="button"
                        Content="-"
                        Width="32"
                        Height="32"
                        Command="{Binding DecreaseCommand}">
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="button1"
                        Content="+"
                        Width="32"
                        Height="32"
                        Command="{Binding IncreaseCommand}">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Did you set Two-way binding in your XAML?

Comment: Have you added an event handler to the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: @Randolf Rincón-Fadul I don't think this is needed here, I'm changing the property values by buttons, please take a look at the project, it is small sample solution which represents my problem.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen♦ - Could you please explain what event handler should be added, I guess I'm missing something. I added the full ViewModelBase code to the question.

Comment: @MyUserName I ask you that cause if your binding mode is set to OneTime then It'll never be updated even if you change your view model. Sorry I'm on my BB can't download files so can't see it.

Comment: @MyUserName: Please show the XAML code where you bind to the Age property.

Comment: Should the view base model be: `ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged `?  I don't think that's the problem though.

Comment: Never mind me, I'm no WPF-expert.

Comment: Yes, thanks for all. I copypasted the INotifyPropertyChanged members, but did not inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your project, you don't actually implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your view-model. You have:

```
public class ViewModelBase
```

But this should be:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Because you don't implement INotifyPropertyChange, the WPF binding system will not be able to add a handler for your PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Wow, thanks! You are totally correct, I though there is something with binding and did not even notice that I don't have INotifyPropertyChanged in view model.

Comment: Just experienced the same, too! :-)

Comment: Thanks, this just solved the same bug I've been experiencing for the last few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your ViewModelBase.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx
You have defined a PropertyChanged event but it is the interface that is important.

Answer (score 1):

I checked you application using [`MVVM-Light`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) instead of your BaseViewModel implementation and it worked as it should.

I suggest using MVVM-Light because of other features like Messaging, Disposing and Blendability.

You can easily download and install it using [`NuGet`](http://nuget.codeplex.com/).

If you want to implement INotifyPropertyChange anyway, here is code that will do it:

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    } 
}
```